# Problem with lando APPSERVER URLS

Tags: 10

I am setting up lando/Drupal 10 on a Mac.  Everything goes OK until:

```
 ⚠ APPSERVER URLS
    ✔ https://localhost:51477 [200]
    ✔ http://localhost:51478 [200]
    ✖ http://drupal10-app.lndo.site/ [ENOTFOUND] GETADDRINFO ENOTFOUND DRUPAL 10 APP LNDO SITE
    ✖ https://drupal10-app.lndo.site/ [ENOTFOUND] GETADDRINFO ENOTFOUND DRUPAL 10 APP LNDO SITE
```

This is in my settings.php:

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = [
  '^.+\.lndo\.site$',
  '^localhost$',
  '127\.0\.0\.1',
  ];
```

but that does not help.  I have tried rebuilding several times but always the same issue.  Has anyone run into this problem?

Comment: What reported in the question is not an error caused by `$settings['trusted_host_patterns']`.

Comment: It's a DNS lookup failure - if you have any other dev tools installed/running, or DNS tools like Dnsmasq enabled, try disabling them. It's not likely to be a problem with Drupal or the Lando Drupal recipe specifically, but you could rule that our for certain by starting up another Lando instance not based on Drupal

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not relate directly to Drupal. Lando has some support channels: https://lando.dev/support